# Loop through Object and replace values based on Regex in given Array

Tags: javascript

I have an object and an array. I try to loop through object keys, check them against a regex in array and then replace the string. What I have so far:

```
let event = {
  "firstKey":"1",
  "secondKey": {
    "a":"one",
    "b":"two",
    "c":"three"
  },
  "id":111934444,
  "count":1,
  "location":"https://www-domain-org/username=steven&tel=1234",
  "title":"lastname=hey",
  "sd":"24-bit"
};
    
let myReg = [
  {
    name: 'telephone',
    reg: /((tel=)|(telephone=))[\d\+\s][^&\/\?]+/gi,
    group: '$1'
  },
  {
    name: 'names',
    reg: /((username=)|(lastname=))[^&\/\?]+/gi,
    group: '$1'
  }
];
    
let secret = function(obj){
  Object.values(obj).forEach(function(val) {
    myReg.forEach(function(regTest) {
      val = val.toString();
      val = val.replace(regTest.reg, regTest.group + '[redacted ' + regTest.name + ']');
    });
  });
  return obj;
}

let newEvent = secret(event);
console.log(newEvent);
```

I do not get the original Object with replaced values. What is wrong with my code? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the local variable `val`. You should actually use the `obj` to persist the change.
Try iterating with `Object.keys(obj)` like this

```js
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    myReg.forEach(function(regTest) {
      let val = obj[key].toString();
      obj[key] = val.replace(regTest.reg, regTest.group + '[redacted ' + regTest.name + ']');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem.